# Proof that $\lim \frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2} = 0 \implies \lim a_n = 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I´ve tried some exercises about sequences convergence, particularly:

> Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence such as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}^2}=0.$ Prove that $a_{n}$ converges to zero.

I've searched for a way to bound $a_{n}$ regarding $\frac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}^2}.$ My attempts have been bounding $\frac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}^2};$ I proved that sequence is bounded between $(0,\frac{1}{2});$ in fact $a_{n}$ is positive but the only logic conclution is $a_{n}>\frac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}^2}.$ I don't think so be helpful.

Some ideas to attack the problem? I'd appreciate your help to follow a proof.

Thanks to everyone for your ideas and time.

Comment: We need more conditions. For example let $a_n=n$.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be true, since if $a_n=n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2} = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not in general true, we need additional conditions on $a_n$. For example, let $a_n=n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}=0$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist.

If we know also that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded, then indeed the limit will be $0$ (Comparison). So if $\lim_{\to\infty} a_n$ exists, then the limit is $0$.

Comment: hmmm... Your observation is very clever @André Nicolas. The stament seeems false under those conditions. I suppouse with this counterexample is enough, Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. As I noted, with additional assumptions on $(a_n)$ the result does hold. In particular, if $(a_n)$ is in addition bounded, it has a limit and that limit is $0$.